# How to update cart by fetching by ID whenever store is updated

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the following component that subscribes to the ngrx store to grab the cart and cartSize:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../state/cart/cart.reducer';
import { select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectCart } from '../state/cart/cart.reducer';
import { CartItem, Product } from '../types';
import { AsyncPipe, NgFor, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { removeItem, updateItem } from '../state/cart/cart.actions';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIf,
    NgFor,
  ],
  selector: 'app-outline',
  templateUrl: './outline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./outline.component.css'],
})
export class OutlineComponent {
  cart$: Observable<CartItem[]>;
  cartSize$: Observable<number>;
  showFiller = false;
  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {
    this.cart$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCart));
    this.cartSize$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCart)).pipe(
      map((_products: CartItem[]) =>
        _products.reduce((total, { quantity }) => total + quantity, 0)
      ),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  removeCartItem(productId: number) {
    this.store.dispatch(removeItem({ productId }));
  }

  addOneItem(productId: number) {
    this.store.dispatch(updateItem({ productId, quantity: 1 }));
  }

  removeOneItem(productId: number) {
    this.store.dispatch(updateItem({ productId, quantity: -1 }));
  }
}
```

Type CartItem is just:

```
export interface CartItem {
  id: number;
  quantity: number;
}
```

Because I was advised not to store entire objects in the store but rather their IDs and in the cart component to grab the objects from the db via the ID.

My question is, how do I update the cart and grab the specific product via ID from the backend every time the user updates the cart?

I have a service for the initial fetch as well as a getProductById function:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  url = 'https://fakestoreapi.com/products';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.url);
  }

  getProductById(productId: number) {
    return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.url}/${productId}`);
  }
}
```

But I have no clue where to put this function, maybe in ngOnChanges?

I've created an effect to fetch the entire object from the db whenever an item is added to the store:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { map, exhaustMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/data.service';
import * as CartActions from './cart.actions';

@Injectable()
export class CartEffects {
  loadProduct$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CartActions.addItem),
      exhaustMap(({ productId }) =>
        this.dataService.getProductById(productId).pipe(
          map((product) => CartActions.loadItemSuccess({ product })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private dataService: DataService) {}
}
```

But now my question is, how do I access the payload of a successful load and add it to the cart array where all the objects are stored?

This is my cart.reducer.ts:

```
import { createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CartItem, Product } from 'src/app/types';
import { addItem, removeItem, updateItem } from './cart.actions';

export interface AppState {
  cart: CartState;
}

export interface CartState {
  cart: CartItem[];
  error: string | null;
  status: 'pending' | 'loading' | 'error' | 'success';
}

export const initialState: CartState = {
  cart: [],
  error: null,
  status: 'pending',
};

export const cartReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addItem, (state, { product }) => {
    const found = state.cart.find((_product) => _product.id === product.id);
    if (found) {
      const updatedCart = state.cart.map((_item) => {
        if (_item.id === product.id) {
          return { ..._item, quantity: _item.quantity + 1 };
        } else return _item;
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: updatedCart,
      };
    }
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: [...state.cart, { ...product, quantity: 1 }],
    };
  }),
  on(removeItem, (state, { productId }) => ({
    ...state,
    cart: state.cart.filter((_item) => _item.id !== productId),
  })),
  on(updateItem, (state, { productId, quantity }) => {
    let removeItem;
    let updatedCart = state.cart.map((_item) => {
      if (_item.id === productId) {
        if (_item.quantity === 1 && quantity === -1) {
          removeItem = 1;
          return _item;
        } else {
          return { ..._item, quantity: _item.quantity + quantity };
        }
      } else {
        return _item;
      }
    });
    if (removeItem) {
      updatedCart = updatedCart.filter((_item) => _item.id !== productId);
    }
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: updatedCart,
    };
  })
);

export const selectCartState = (state: AppState) => state.cart;
export const selectCart = createSelector(
  selectCartState,
  (state: CartState) => state.cart
);
```

and my cart.actions.ts:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CartItem, Product } from 'src/app/types';

export const addItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Add Item',
  props<{ product: CartItem }>()
);
export const removeItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Remove Item',
  props<{ productId: number }>()
);
export const updateItem = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Edit Item',
  props<{ productId: number; quantity: number }>()
);
export const loadItemSuccess = createAction(
  '[Cart Page] Load Item Success',
  props<{ product: Product }>()
);
```

I'm not sure how to correctly use the loadItemSuccess action, I just know it's standard to include successful and nonsuccessful actions

Comment: I don't quite understand how the logic of items, cart are related in your project. I want to understand it better. You have a cart where the user might add/remove products on it right? but the cart only has a product id and a quantity, and now you are asking `how do I update the cart and grab the specific product via ID`, you would only update the quantity from the cart right? there is nothing more to update, why do you need the product data for updating the product quantity?

Comment: Additionally, the action `loadItemSuccess`, where does it store the product from the API in the ngrx store? and when is this action triggered? when adding an item to the cart?

Comment: Please add your state and reducers as well. Currently the only logical answer is to add a reducer that will modify the state (i.e., `add it to the cart array where all the objects are stored`) after `loadItemSuccess` was published. But I think you want to do something else, right?

Comment: @Andres2142 I'm only adding the id's of the products to the store and I'd like the cart component to match each ID with the appropriate product info whenever the store is updated (i.e. item is added or updated etc). I was thinking to fetch from the db every time an item is added (for example, in the addOneItem function and then add that returned value to the cart that way) but this falls short as the cart component is seperate from the main product page where users click the item to add it

Comment: @VolodymyrUsarskyy I've added the actions and reducers

Comment: @Mathew I am thinking about something like Amazon, the user sees the item and wants to add it to the cart, so I am assuming that, somewhere in the store, you have that item information... if you are only adding the product id in the store then just grab the product from the store and match it with the id. If that is not the case, then how is the product displayed to the user? in other words, the product information, where is located in the store? or the project in general?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you add the reducer logic for the action `loadItemSuccess`, to see what happens there, It looks like you already have the product info somewhere in the store, and you also have the id, if I am getting this right, just create a selector, grab the product from wherever it is in the store and match it with the id every time the user adds or updates the quantity...

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I update the cart and grab the specific product
> via ID from the backend every time the user updates the cart?

Okay, after the question was updated I can give the answer to your question: simply add the reducer for `loadItemSuccess` (BUT looking at your code I can also suggest to rename `loadItemSuccess` to `itemAdded` to make things clear).

The only problem of the final solution is that your code is actually "broken by design" because you will have two sequential reducers (a workflow) that modify the same piece of your state based on same intent. Furthermore, first reducer leaves gaps that must be filled by the second! So, if the second reducer is not executed, your state will be left broken.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Change the reducer for `addItem` action to `loadItemSuccess` (i.e., `itemAdded`) reducer. Basically, you will update the cart once and only when all the required information is available (i.e., product information from the server).
2. Forget about the advise `not to store entire objects in the store` because IMHO it doesn't make any sense. There are a few use cases where it is applicable but in your case this approach is very questionable. Then you don't need to make an extra backend call which eliminates the problem (BUT don't forget that you shouldn't copy the backend DB structure, certain denormalization and optimizations is okay for frontend store).

IMPORTANT: The only thing I miss in this puzzle is the `loadItemSuccess` reducer. I suppose that you have an extra collection in your state where you keep a list of added products and join this list with the cart state to show this list on the shopping cart page. In this case you split your state into two pieces which is wrong.